# How to reference named column in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spread sheet where all of column A is a named range called "Michael".

I am getting the row number of the last occupied row.

This code works:
     `LRow = Worksheets("Head").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

This code does not work:
     `LRow = Worksheets("Head").Range("Michael" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

How do I get this to work with me using the column name "Michael" and not the default A?

Answer (score 4):

You would refer to the column and row count of the range inside Cells() range object:

```
LRow = Cells(Range("micheal").Rows.count, Range("micheal").Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Find` is recommended rather than `xlUp`. Both approaches shown below

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lRow As Long

'Option 1
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Range("Michael").Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Option 2
Set rng1 = Range("Michael").Find("*", Range("Michael")(1), , , xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng1.Row
```